# Wget- Skip hosts that are down

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I'm using wget to bulk download a website, and it grabs files from other servers, however, some hosts are down. All wget does is just hang there, so I'd like it to just skip these  websites. Is there a flag that I can use to skip downed hosts?

Comment: Would setting a timeout help? See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291524/does-wget-timeout.

Comment: @berndbausch Yep! It worked perfectly! Thanks